# EOFException in readObject

Tags: java, android

Hello I create serialized file via Output stream, and send it via email, on the other device I want to open this file and read data this file isn't empty, I get EOFException, I read file in this way

```
 Uri uriToOpen = data.getData();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            if (uriToOpen != null) {
                try {
                    InputStream stream = cr.openInputStream(uriToOpen);
                    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(stream);


                    ArrayList<String> text= (ArrayList<String>) inputStream.readObject();

                    inputStream.close();
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I don't know why

Comment: post the error log

Comment: The stream doesn't contain an entire object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An EOFException is thrown when there is no more data to be read/it has reached the end. So you can ignore this exception if you are able to read data from the file.

While writing your file, you can keep a count of number of objects in your file and handle the ObjectInputStream accordingly.

Comment: Ok I solve it, first I save a number and next objects, during reading I read number and using loop I read Objects

Comment: Yes! I don't think there is any other way to solve it. This is an issue with Java language. So use the number of objects and next loop it over the number of objects so that you don't get this exception.

Comment: There is no file here. It is a URL. If you get this exception you *weren't* able to read the stream, and you can't 'ignore' it: you have to close the stream and stop reading from it. Once you've started writing objects, it is pointless to court the objects, as you would need to put the count at the front and it is already too late. Answer is almost meaningless after the first sentence.